# Creating stub files for ejb in maven build tool

Tags: maven, ejb, stub, continuum

Team,

Our project makes use of EJB, was 6.1 is our server, While deploying the code , am in need of stub files to be present in EAR (Maven Generated). Inorder to achieve this, am using was6 plug in our pom.xml

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>was6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
        <execution>
           <goals>
                    <goal>ejbdeploy</goal>
            </goals>
         </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
        <archive>
        <manifest>
               <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                     <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
        </manifest>
        </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

For this we need to set the environment variables "WAS_HOME".

But we cannot set the wasHome in continuum build server and hence we are getting BUILD ERROR -  "wasHome not defined"

Is that any other way to achieve this?
- Creating the stub files for all ejb class without using WAS 6 maven plugin in Maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inorder to achieve this we can set the parameter`(ejbdeploy = true)` in was6 server install configuration xml
and its worked.

Thanks for all the responses.

Answer (score 1):

WAS6_HOME environment variable is the default value used by was6-maven-plugin to know where Websphere is located, 
but people often use the wasHome attribute to indicate this.

From here it's possible to use Maven properties in the pom or in the settings file and Maven profiles.

On the other hand, you can generate the EJB Stubs without the maven plugin, but you will always need to know where websphere is installed.

Regards