# EJB 2 STUBS & TIES generation through Maven

Tags: maven, ejb, pom.xml, xdoclet, rmic

Recently I started working for migrating the EJB project to Maven Project. We use EJB 2.0 in our project, I don't know were to start about migration process, currently the existing EJB project includes STUBS & TIES(Through RAD tool we generate the jar file.). Not sure how can I make this Maven to have STUBS & TIES included in the jar which I'm generating through the Maven process.

Below is the POM.xml

```
<profile>
    <id>xdoclet</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>xdoclet</name>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>xdoclet-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xdoclet</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <ejbdoclet
                                        destDir="${project.build.sourceDirectory}"
                                        force="true" ejbSpec="2.0"
                                        verbose="true">
                                    <fileset
                                            dir="${project.build.sourceDirectory}">
                                        <include name="**/*Bean.java" />
                                    </fileset>
                                    <packageSubstitution
                                            packages="service" useFirst="true"
                                            substituteWith="interface" />
                                    <homeinterface />
                                    <remoteinterface />
                                    <deploymentdescriptor
                                            displayname="Service Name"
                                            description=""
                                            destDir="${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF"
                                            validateXML="true" useIds="true" />
                                    <websphere
                                            destDir="${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF"
                                            validateXML="true" />
                                </ejbdoclet>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>was-ejb</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>was-ejb</name>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>was6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>ejbdeploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <wasHome>C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer</wasHome>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

I went through the below links, none of them helped in achieving the functionality.
[Creating stub files for ejb in maven build tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373608/creating-stub-files-for-ejb-in-maven-build-tool/22457792#22457792)

[How to instruct maven-ejb-plugin to only include required classes in client EJB package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37166305/how-to-instruct-maven-ejb-plugin-to-only-include-required-classes-in-client-ejb/64971185#64971185)

Comment: Are you sure you need to generate the stubs/ties when packaging?   WebSphere can typically generate them for you during EAR deployment.   I'm not familiar with either of those two plugins, so not sure whether to suggest using them differently, OR, alternatively, doing something like using "maven-antrun-plugin"  to call the ejbDeploy script, and then configuring the plugins to zip up / package the correct artifacts.

Comment: Yes. I need them during packaging the jar itself.

Comment: so what exactly is the output of the excution of the plugin? I think we are using the way you intend, but it's hard to guess what your problem is.

Comment: Plugin just generates the EJB file in it, but not stubs & ties in the jar. Can you show us your POM.xml?